# How to redirect user if max connections reached NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have a download server with a 1 Gbps connection. Problem is, that uplink often gets saturated due to some large files. To ensure download quality, I want to limit the number of concurrent downloads on the server, so in nginx.conf I set `workers_connection` to `1024`.

My issue is sometimes I have more than 1024 users trying to download a file. Is there any way I can tell NGINX to redirect to a custom page after, say, 1000 connections are used to tell the user that server is underload and to try again shortly? If that page can be a PHP page -- so that I can automatically refresh for the user -- so much the better.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you could consider using a CDN or AWS S3 to host your files. That removes the bandwidth limitation, will be faster for your users too.

Comment: @Tim It also would cost thousands of dollars, which unfortunately we cannot afford.

Comment: I wonder if CloudFlare free tier would cache large files for you.

Comment: @Tim Already doing that. CloudFlare has a limit on file size though.

Comment: I've done a bit of reading, and I can't find a good way to do this. You could look at [limit rate](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_rate) or limit_rate_after rather than workers_connection and see if that takes you anywhere, but if you have fewer users that would prevent all your bandwidth being used. I wonder if you can write some kind of script that will count current connections and if it's higher than your number show a page. This really is a job for a CDN, but yes they have a cost.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, I have limit_Rate and limit_rate_after in place, but the issue is exactly as you mention. I'll update if I find a solution.